# Python class outputting hex value instead of list, not sure why?

Tags: python, list, class, program-entry-point

```
class SList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s1 = ['hey']
    def take(self, item):
        self.s1 += [item]
        return self.s1
    def size(self):
        size = len(self.s1)
        return size

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    s1 = SList()
    print('hello')
    s1.take(33)
    s1.take(42)
    s1.take(55)
    s1.size()
    print(s1)
    print(s1.size())
```

Not too familiar with classes, wrote this more for proof of concept than anything so I could familiarize myself with it. I can't seem to figure out why the output from this is:

> `hello`
>
> `<__main__.SList object at 0x3323ed0>`
>
> `4`

`hello` and `4` are the way I want them, but I seem to get a hexadecimal value for `s1`, when I need `s1` to output: `['hey', 33, 42, 55]`

Wow to get `s1` to output the correct list?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rewrite the `str` method to output what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Add an override of [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) or [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str):

```
class SList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s1 = ['hey']

    def take(self, item):
        self.s1 += [item]
        return self.s1

    def size(self):
        size = len(self.s1)
        return size

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.s1)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    s1 = SList()
    print('hello')
    s1.take(33)
    s1.take(42)
    s1.take(55)
    s1.size()
    print(s1)
    print(s1.size())
```

This will suffice in your case:

> hello
>
> ['hey', 33, 42, 55]
>
> 4

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) about `__repr__`:

> Called by the repr() built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines **repr**() but not **str**(), then **repr**() is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.
>
> This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous.

For completeness you can also override [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str):

> Called by the str() built-in function and by the print statement to compute the “informal” string representation of an object. This differs from **repr**() in that it does not have to be a valid Python expression: a more convenient or concise representation may be used instead. The return value must be a string object.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
print(s1)
```

use

```
print(s1.s1)
```

as in the original case you are printing an instance object of SList class.